# Azure storage queue not found

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues

I have an azure storage queue, every now and again I get an exception logged in application insights of:

```
Error processing responsys messages: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

A call milliseconds later could them succeed. Has any one experienced this before or know of a reason as to why this might occur other that a transient failure?

Cheer
Mark

Comment: This is weird. Azure Storage is a `Strongly Consistent` system. I am wondering if there are multiple threads involved i.e. one thread trying to create a queue while the other thread is reading from the queue. Can you share some code?

Comment: I will try to pick some code out but it will take a while to split it out of the system. However, we are not creating the queue if it does not exists (design decision by someone else, not sure why). We are contacting the queue on multiple threads but it would not be extensive.